# Main Layout where Scrolling is only active in the main Content-Div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently working on a GUI-Layout which can be reused.
So I just want a basic header, mainContainer and a Footer.

I tried multiple things.
The problem is that I don't know how to define the hight of the  properly.

```css
html body{
 margin: 0;
 background-color: red;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
}

.header{
 height: 64px;
 min-height: 64px;
 background-color: blue;
}

.mainContainer{
 background-color: gray; 
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 min-width: 800px;
 min-height: 600px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.footer{
 height: 20px; 
 min-height: 20px; 
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="mainContainer">

</div>

<div class="footer">

</div>
```

Header should 64px high. Footer should be 20px.
The mainContainer should then fill the rest of Website.
But if the size of the page gets too small then a scrollbar should appear but only inside the mainContainer.

Comment: As I understood, you want the header and the footer to be always visible even if there's a scrolling content ?

Comment: yes footer and header should always be visible

Comment: see my answer then if you want.

Comment: thanks ver much :-)

Comment: you're welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` along with specifuing a `height` for the `.mainContainer` with `calc` function and also specifying an `overflow: auto` to allow scrolling only in that element.

Here's a demo :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap; /** elements are stacked vertically without line breaks **/
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  min-height: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  max-height: 64px;
  background-color: red;
}

.footer {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.mainContainer {
  min-height: calc(100% - (64px + 20px)); /** height = 100% of parent height which is 100vh minus (header height + footer height) **/
  overflow: auto; /** allow scrolling if needed **/
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro necessitatibus dolorum deleniti excepturi vel numquam reiciendis impedit. Natus neque reiciendis ea voluptatibus, vero explicabo odit harum perspiciatis fugiat rerum nemo!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc` css for this. check attach snippet

```css
html body{
 margin: 0;
 background-color: red;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
}

.header{
 height: 64px;
 min-height: 64px;
 background-color: blue;
}

.mainContainer{
 background-color: gray; 
 height: calc(100vh - 64px - 20px);
 width: 100vw;
 min-width: 800px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.footer{
 height: 20px; 
 height: 20px; 
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="mainContainer">

</div>

<div class="footer">

</div>
```